# Returning an object from a function

Tags: c++, function, object, data-structures

The other day I was trying to write a matrix manipulation program in C++. I first created a matrix container which works. Then I tried to write a function for transposing matrices. That's when I got into trouble. Using the function causes my program to crash.

```
struct imat //matrix of integer numbers
{
friend int size(imat,int);
protected:
  const int nrows; const int ncols; //ncols = number of columns, nrows = number of rows
  int* mat; //internal array that holds the data
public:
  imat(const int m, const int n): nrows(m), ncols(n) //constructor
  {
    mat = new int[m*n]; //creates an array of size nrows*ncols
    for (int k=0; k<m*n; k++) mat[k]=0; //zeros all the elements
  }
  imat(const imat& src): nrows(src.nrows), ncols(src.ncols) //copy constructor
    {for (int k=0; k<nrows*ncols; k++) mat[k]=src.mat[k];} //copies the contents of src to this matrix
  imat& operator=(const imat& rhs) //assignment operator
  {
    if (nrows!=rhs.nrows||ncols!=rhs.ncols) throw(1); //lhs and rhs must have the same dimensions
    for (int k=0; k<nrows*ncols; k++) mat[k]=rhs.mat[k]; //copies the contents of rhs to this matrix (lhs)
    return *this; //return this matrix as output (lhs)
  }
  int& operator()(int i, int j) {return mat[(i-1)*ncols+(j-1)];} //A(i,j)=mat[(i-1)*ncols+(j-1)] (stores the matrix in the 1D array 'mat')
 ~imat() {delete[] mat;}
};

int size(imat mat, int dim) //gets matrix dimensions
{
  if (dim==1) return mat.nrows; //dimension 1 is number of rows
  if (dim==2) return mat.ncols; //dimernsion 2 is number of columns
  return 0; //returns 0 if dimesion number is invalid
}

imat trans(imat A)
{
  int m=size(A,1); //number of rows
  int n=size(A,2); //numbers of columns
  imat B(n,m); //creates an n*m matrix
  for (int i=1; i<=m; i++)
    for (int j=1; j<=n; j++)
      B(j,i)=A(i,j); //sets the components of B to the components of the transpose of A
  return B;
}
```

I tried the following main functions, but none of them works:

1)

```
int main()
{
  imat A(2,3);

  A(1,1)=11;
  A(1,2)=12;
  A(1,3)=13;
  A(2,1)=21;
  A(2,2)=22;
  A(2,3)=23;

  imat B = trans(A);

  return 0;
}
```

2)

```
int main()
{
  imat A(2,3);

  A(1,1)=11;
  A(1,2)=12;
  A(1,3)=13;
  A(2,1)=21;
  A(2,2)=22;
  A(2,3)=23;

  imat B(3,2)
  B = trans(A);

  return 0;
}
```

My guess is that it has something to do with the destruction of objects at the end of a function scope, though I'm not sure. Please explain to me in simple language what the problem is and how I can fix it.

Comment: Have you tried debugging? Where does it crash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to allocate memory for your dynamic array in the copy constructor.  You just started assigning to `mat[...]`, even though `mat` was left uninitialized.